# Ag-grid sticky header

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ag-grid

So my ag-grid resize itself because my row height is also dynamic. So for height I am using `[style.height.px]="beta"` and `this.beta = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-full-width-container')["0"].offsetHeight + 139` And the `pagination` is set to `100`.

I cannot use `autoHeight` because I have more than 10k rows. So I want my header to be sticky. I have some content before ag-grid in DOM. As I scroll I want my ag-grid header to stick to the top. I am using `top:0;position:sticky;z-index:1000` It's working for every `div` tag except `ag-gird`'s `div` tag. So is there a way to have a sticky header in ag-grid?

Comment: Negative vote but now comment ?

Comment: @MindRoasterMir What?

Comment: someone gave you a negative comment but he did not give a reason.

Comment: Yeah, the question was beyond their level of understanding.

Comment: @Shlok Nangia Hey, i want to make a scrollable but horizonatally, for group header text, when i scroll right the text group it shows the next header group text is first. a kind of gradient, but not for color for header group text.

Comment: @Racal are you looking for something called column pinning?

Comment: @NamanJain yes but for horizontal scroll, how could i do that ? In angular of course.

Comment: @Racal I hope this is what you are looking for https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-pinning/

Comment: @NamanJain something like, but for group https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grouping-multiple-group-columns/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `onGridViewChanged()` function I implemented the following logic. So in this logic the `HTML` above `ag-gird` in DOM should be consider for `top` because ag-grid header `top` was `0` for me. And then add some value according to your requirement (calibration). Then for the row body add some `margin` (calibration).

```
    onGridViewChanged() {
        let header = $('.ag-header')
        let headerPos = $('.btn-row').position().top + 50
        $(window).on("scroll", function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerPos) {
                header.css("position", "fixed").css("top", 0).css("z-index", "99");
                $('.ag-body-viewport.ag-layout-normal').css("margin-top", "88px");
            }
            else {
                header.css("position", "static");
                $('.ag-body-viewport.ag-layout-normal').css("margin-top", "0px");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest eliminating the scrollbars that are outside of the grid, and make the grid fit within the window. You can use flexbox to do that. You need to make sure the parent elements are using `display: flex` and have 100% height. And then set the grid to be `flex-grow: 1`.

On the parent element(s):

```
height: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

On the grid:

```
flex-grow: 1;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-full-height?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: The content above the grid is very big so I can't eliminate the mainpage scrollbar.

Comment: @Naman I understand your situation now. And I'm guessing you don't want to have a hardcoded height on the grid, because then there will be multiple scrollbars on the page? If that is the case then sorry but I don't know of a good solution.

Comment: Yeah. Grid's height is dynamic. I just want to know why `position:sticky;top:0;z-index:9999` is not working

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many things but this worked for me. Here .grid-table is my custom class. Also this solution will not work if you have externally given overflow to the class.

```
::ng-deep .grid-table .ag-body-viewport {        
        overflow: auto;               
    }
```